# Improve the error message when a user try to create a tag synonym

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I think it would be worth improving the error message when a user tries to create a tag synonym.

The current message (in red):

[image]

Issues:

- doesn't say it has to be an answer score (not question score)
- unclear whether it's complaining about the `to` or `from` tag
- unsure if `requires 5 score` is proper English.